# Move inherited item with Drag and Drop within QStandardItemModel

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to implement a function to move nodes by dragging in a single tree (QStandardItemModel, PyQt5, Python). My nodes are classes created by multiple inheritance like `class Node(A, QStandardItem)`. When I drag and drop this node, only properties from QStandardItem parent class are moved, everything from the class A is lost.
Here is minimal working example:

````
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QModelIndex, QMimeData, QByteArray)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QAbstractItemView, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem


class A:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.symbol = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # forwards all unused arguments

class Node(A, QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, symbol, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.symbol = symbol

        self.setText("Node " + str(self.symbol))

class DragDropTreeModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DragDropTreeModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def supportedDropActions(self):
        return Qt.MoveAction

    def flags(self, index):
        defaultFlags = QStandardItemModel.flags(self, index)

        if index.isValid():
            return Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags
        else:
            return Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags```

class DemoDragDrop(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DemoDragDrop, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('drag&drop in PyQt5')

        self.resize(480, 320)

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.vLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.TreeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)
        self.TreeView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.TreeView.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.TreeView.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.TreeView.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.ddm = DragDropTreeModel()
        self.TreeView.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.TreeView.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        self.TreeView.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)

        self.root_node = Node('root')
        self.ddm.appendRow(self.root_node)
        node_a = Node('a')
        self.root_node.appendRow(node_a)
        node_b = Node('b')
        self.root_node.appendRow(node_b)
        node_c = Node('c')
        self.root_node.appendRow(node_c)

        self.TreeView.setModel(self.ddm)

        self.printButton = QPushButton("Print")

        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.TreeView)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.printButton)

        self.printButton.clicked.connect(self.printModelProp)

    def printModelProp(self):
        cur_ind = self.TreeView.currentIndex()
        obj = self.ddm.itemFromIndex(cur_ind)
        obj: Node
        print(obj.symbol)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('fusion')
    window = DemoDragDrop()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
````

In this example, select the node from the tree and click "Print" button - it will print to the console, 'a' for "Node a", 'b' for "Node b" and so on. Then move one node, select it and push "Print" again. The application will crash with the error `AttributeError: 'QStandardItem' object has no attribute 'symbol'`.

Then I tried to move a node manually by overriding methods `mimeData` and `dropMimeData`. I saved row and column indexes in mimeData and tried to get this node from the index in dropMimeData to move it. But this doesn't work because the index has changed meanwhile.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QModelIndex, QMimeData, QByteArray)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QAbstractItemView, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem


class A:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.symbol = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # forwards all unused arguments

class Node(A, QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, symbol, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.symbol = symbol

        self.setText("Node " + str(self.symbol))

class DragDropTreeModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DragDropTreeModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def supportedDropActions(self):
        return Qt.MoveAction

    def flags(self, index):
        defaultFlags = QStandardItemModel.flags(self, index)

        if index.isValid():
            return Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags
        else:
            return Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags

    def mimeData(self, indexes) -> QtCore.QMimeData:
        m_data = super().mimeData(indexes)
        if (m_data):
            r = indexes[0].row()
            c = indexes[0].column()
            obj = self.itemFromIndex(indexes[0])
            print(f"row:{r}, column:{c}, type:{type(obj)}, ind:{indexes[0]}")
            m_data.setData('row', QByteArray.number(indexes[0].row()))
            m_data.setData('col', QByteArray.number(indexes[0].column()))
        return m_data

    def dropMimeData(self, data: QtCore.QMimeData, action: QtCore.Qt.DropAction, row: int, column: int,
                     parent: QtCore.QModelIndex) -> bool:
        if data is None or action != QtCore.Qt.MoveAction:
            return False

        _row = data.data('row').toInt()[0]
        _col = data.data('col').toInt()[0]

        old_index = self.index(_row, _col)
        current_index = parent

        old_item = self.takeItem(old_index.row(), old_index.column())
        parent_item = self.itemFromIndex(parent)
        parent_item.appendRow(old_item)

        return True


class DemoDragDrop(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DemoDragDrop, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('drag&drop in PyQt5')

        self.resize(480, 320)

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.vLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.TreeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)
        self.TreeView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.TreeView.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.TreeView.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.TreeView.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.ddm = DragDropTreeModel()
        self.TreeView.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.TreeView.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        self.TreeView.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)

        self.root_node = Node('root')
        self.ddm.appendRow(self.root_node)
        node_a = Node('a')
        self.root_node.appendRow(node_a)
        node_b = Node('b')
        self.root_node.appendRow(node_b)
        node_c = Node('c')
        self.root_node.appendRow(node_c)

        self.TreeView.setModel(self.ddm)

        self.printButton = QPushButton("Print")

        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.TreeView)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.printButton)

        self.printButton.clicked.connect(self.printModelProp)

    def printModelProp(self):
        cur_ind = self.TreeView.currentIndex()
        obj = self.ddm.itemFromIndex(cur_ind)
        obj: Node
        print(obj.symbol)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('fusion')
    window = DemoDragDrop()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In this example the tree will break.

I wonder is there a way to move the node without destroying it. It seems to me a wrong way to recreate the object (in `mimeData()` and `dropMimeData()`) when it's only needed to change the index.

So, the questions are: how to implement this move correctly, and is it possible without destroying the node (it can be a member of some list for example)?

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody replied, I post an answer to my own question (maybe it's not perfect but it works).
First, I found that my design doesn't fit Qt's drag-n-drop design. One way is not to subclass an item using multiple inheritance (like `class Node(A, QStandardItem)`) but rather to use composition and keep `class A` within `QStandardItem` using roles. Then no need to override any methods.

In my case nodes are using multiple inheritance so I did override dropEvent method and move row (extract it from the model and insert in the new place). It's very simple example just for demonstration, so no checks what kind of object is dropping and so on.

If somebody has better idea - you're welcome to comment or write your own solution

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QModelIndex, QMimeData, QByteArray)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QAbstractItemView, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem


class A:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.symbol = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # forwards all unused arguments

class Node(A, QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, symbol, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.setData(symbol, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)

        self.setText("Node " + str(self.symbol))

    def get_sym(self):
        return self.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)

class DragDropTreeModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DragDropTreeModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def supportedDropActions(self):
        return Qt.MoveAction

    def flags(self, index):
        defaultFlags = QStandardItemModel.flags(self, index)

        if index.isValid():
            return Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags
        else:
            return Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags

class MyTreeView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTreeView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
        model = self.model()
        dest_node = model.itemFromIndex(index)
        if dest_node is None:
            return

        source_index = self.currentIndex()
        source_node = model.itemFromIndex(source_index)
        source_node: Node
        sourse_parent = source_node.parent()
        taken_row = sourse_parent.takeRow(source_index.row())

        dest_parent = dest_node
        if dest_node != sourse_parent:
            dest_parent = dest_node.parent()
            if dest_parent is None:
                dest_parent = dest_node

        dest_parent.insertRow(index.row(), taken_row)

class DemoDragDrop(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DemoDragDrop, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('drag&drop in PyQt5')

        self.resize(480, 320)

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.vLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.TreeView = MyTreeView(self)# QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)#
        self.TreeView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.TreeView.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.TreeView.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.TreeView.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.ddm = DragDropTreeModel()
        self.TreeView.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.TreeView.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        self.TreeView.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)

        self.root_node = Node('root')
        self.ddm.appendRow(self.root_node)
        node_1 = Node('1')
        self.root_node.appendRow(node_1)
        node_2 = Node('2')
        self.root_node.appendRow(node_2)
        node_d = Node('d')
        node_2.appendRow(node_d)
        node_a = Node('a')
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        node_a.setFont(font)
        node_1.appendRow(node_a)
        node_b = Node('b')
        node_1.appendRow(node_b)
        node_c = Node('c')
        node_1.appendRow(node_c)

        self.TreeView.setModel(self.ddm)

        self.printButton = QPushButton("Print")

        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.TreeView)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.printButton)

        self.printButton.clicked.connect(self.printModelProp)

    def drop(self):
        print('drop')

    def printModelProp(self):
        cur_ind = self.TreeView.currentIndex()
        obj = self.ddm.itemFromIndex(cur_ind)
        obj: Node
        print(obj.symbol)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('fusion')
    window = DemoDragDrop()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```